# Unable to run project in SharpDevelop

Tags: .net, dll, ironpython, cas, sharpdevelop

We got a project from a development company and we'd like to maintain the code from time to time.

The project was made using SharpDevelop 4.4 and IronPython 2.7.4

I can import the solution into SharpDevelop but when I try to run it I get the message:

> Traceback most recent call last: File "Common\Program.py", line 26,
> in module
>
> SystemError: An attempt was made to load an assembly from a
> network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed
> in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET
> Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be
> dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly,
> please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. See
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.

Line 26 being: `clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(Global.configurationmanagerlibrary_dll_path)`

I checked out this website: [Loading blocked and network-hosted assemblies with .NET4](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2011/07/loading-blocked-and-network-hosted-assemblies-with-net-4.html)

and tried adding:

```
<runtime>         
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

but that didn't work.

I also right-clicked>properties unlocked every .dll in the project directory.

Any tips on what I'm missing?

Also, I have installed .NET Framework Versions: 3.0, 3.5, 4.6 according to: [.NET Framework Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed)

Edit: This is the project's structure:

```
├───.idea
│   │   d_o_GM.iml
│   │   encodings.xml
│   │   misc.xml
│   │   modules.xml
│   │   workspace.xml
│   │
│   ├───dictionaries
│   │       user.xml
│   │
│   └───inspectionProfiles
│           profiles_settings.xml
│           Project_Default.xml
│
├───.vs
│   │   ProjectSettings.json
│   │   slnx.sqlite
│   │   VSWorkspaceState.json
│   │
│   └───d_o_GM
│       └───v15
├───bin
│   ├───Installer_DO
│   │   │   DO_Installer.iss
│   │   │
│   │   ├───Fonts
│   │   │       Exo2-Black.otf
│   │   │       Exo2-BlackItalic.otf
│   │   │
│   │   └───Output
│   │           Setup_DO.exe
│   │
│   └───Publish
│       └───Publish_V.1.0
│           │   ConfigurationManagerLibrary.dll
│           │   IronPython.dll
│           │   IronPython.Modules.dll
│           │   ListViewLibrary.dll
│           │   MessageBoxLibrary.dll
│           │   Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
│           │   Microsoft.Scripting.dll
│           │   Microsoft.Scripting.Metadata.dll
│           │   M.DO.dll
│           │   M.DO.exe
│           │   MDO.exe.config
│           │   M.DO.Process.exe
│           │   M.DO.Process.exe.config
│           │
│           ├───AppDesktop
│           │   │   enAppDesktop.idiom.config
│           │   │   pt-brAppDesktop.idiom.config
│           │   │
│           │   ├───DLL
│           │   │       ListViewLibrary.dll
│           │   │       MessageBoxLibrary.dll
│           │   │
│           │   └───Images
│           │           ImageButtonManual.png
│           │           ImageTabPageScheduled.png
│           │
│           ├───Common
│           │   │   app.config
│           │   │   enCommon.idiom.config
│           │   │   pt-brCommon.idiom.config
│           │   │
│           │   └───DLL
│           │           ConfigurationManagerLibrary.dll
│           │
│           └───Process
│                   billing_situation_R1.txt
│                   billing_situation_R2.txt
│                   reason_for_billing_status_R1.txt
│                   reason_for_billing_status_R2.txt
│
├───doc
│       Manual.docx
│
├───sql
│       test_arq_rem.sql
│       TCO2.PSFD.MOVCD2.Tppppp.Oeeeee.00000.Caammdd.hhmmss
│       uf.ARD05.TERppppp.ENaammdd.PLUS
│       uf.ARD06.TERppppp.ENaammdd.PLUS
│
└───src
    ├───DO
    │   │   DO.sln
    │   │
    │   └───M.DO
    │       │   M.DO.pyproj
    │       │   M.DO.sln
    │       │
    │       ├───AppDesktop
    │       │   │   enAppDesktop.idiom.config
    │       │   │   pt-brAppDesktop.idiom.config
    │       │   │
    │       │   ├───DAO
    │       │   │   └───Persistence
    │       │   │           PersistenceAppDesktopShipping.py
    │       │   │
    │       │   ├───DLL
    │       │   │       ListViewLibrary.dll
    │       │   │       MessageBoxLibrary.dll
    │       │   │
    │       │   ├───Form
    │       │   │       FrmLoading.py
    │       │   │       FrmLoading.resx
    │       │   │       FrmShipping.py
    │       │   │       FrmShipping.resx
    │       │   │       FrmSplashScreen.py
    │       │   │       FrmSplashScreen.resx
    │       │   │
    │       │   ├───Images
    │       │   │       ImageButtonManual.png
    │       │   │       ImageButtonScheduled.png
    │       │   │       ImageTabPageScheduled.png
    │       │   │
    │       │   └───UsefulClasses
    │       │           LanguageAppDesktop.py
    │       │           UtilAppDesktop.py
    │       │
    │       ├───bin
    │       │   ├───Debug
    │       │   │   │   ConfigurationManagerLibrary.dll
    │       │   │   │   IronPython.dll
    │       │   │   │   IronPython.Modules.dll
    │       │   │   │   ListViewLibrary.dll
    │       │   │   │   MessageBoxLibrary.dll
    │       │   │   │   Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
    │       │   │   │   Microsoft.Scripting.dll
    │       │   │   │   Microsoft.Scripting.Metadata.dll
    │       │   │   │   M.DO.dll
    │       │   │   │   M.DO.exe
    │       │   │   │   M.DO.exe.config
    │       │   │   │
    │       │   │   ├───AppDesktop
    │       │   │   │   │   enAppDesktop.idiom.config
    │       │   │   │   │   pt-brAppDesktop.idiom.config
    │       │   │   │   │
    │       │   │   │   ├───DLL
    │       │   │   │   │       ListViewLibrary.dll
    │       │   │   │   │       MessageBoxLibrary.dll
    │       │   │   │   │
    │       │   │   │   └───Images
    │       │   │   │           ImageButtonManual.png
    │       │   │   │           ImageButtonScheduled.png
    │       │   │   │           ImageTabPageScheduled.png
    │       │   │   │
    │       │   │   ├───Common
    │       │   │   │   │   app.config
    │       │   │   │   │   enCommon.idiom.config
    │       │   │   │   │   pt-brCommon.idiom.config
    │       │   │   │   │
    │       │   │   │   └───DLL
    │       │   │   │           ConfigurationManagerLibrary.dll
    │       │   │   │
    │       │   │   └───Process
    │       │   │           billing_situation_R1.txt
    │       │   │           billing_situation_R2.txt
    │       │   │           reason_for_billing_status_R1.txt
    │       │   │           reason_for_billing_status_R2.txt
    │       │   │
    │       │   └───Release
    │       │       │   ConfigurationManagerLibrary.dll
    │       │       │   IronPython.dll
    │       │       │   IronPython.Modules.dll
    │       │       │   ListViewLibrary.dll
    │       │       │   MessageBoxLibrary.dll
    │       │       │   Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
    │       │       │   Microsoft.Scripting.dll
    │       │       │   Microsoft.Scripting.Metadata.dll
    │       │       │   M.DO.dll
    │       │       │   M.DO.exe
    │       │       │   M.DO.exe.config
    │       │       │
    │       │       ├───AppDesktop
    │       │       │   │   enAppDesktop.idiom.config
    │       │       │   │   pt-brAppDesktop.idiom.config
    │       │       │   │
    │       │       │   ├───DLL
    │       │       │   │       ListViewLibrary.dll
    │       │       │   │       MessageBoxLibrary.dll
    │       │       │   │
    │       │       │   └───Images
    │       │       │           ImageButtonManual.png
    │       │       │           ImageButtonScheduled.png
    │       │       │           ImageTabPageScheduled.png
    │       │       │
    │       │       ├───Common
    │       │       │   │   app.config
    │       │       │   │   enCommon.idiom.config
    │       │       │   │   pt-brCommon.idiom.config
    │       │       │   │
    │       │       │   └───DLL
    │       │       │           ConfigurationManagerLibrary.dll
    │       │       │
    │       │       └───Process
    │       │               billing_situation_R1.txt
    │       │               billing_situation_R2.txt
    │       │               reason_for_billing_status_R1.txt
    │       │               reason_for_billing_status_R2.txt
    │       │
    │       ├───Common
    │       │   │   app.config
    │       │   │   enCommon.idiom.config
    │       │   │   Program.py
    │       │   │   pt-brCommon.idiom.config
    │       │   │
    │       │   ├───DAO
    │       │   │   ├───Connection
    │       │   │   │       ManagerConnectionSqlServer.py
    │       │   │   │
    │       │   │   └───Persistence
    │       │   │           PersistenceCommonShipping.py
    │       │   │
    │       │   ├───DLL
    │       │   │       ConfigurationManagerLibrary.dll
    │       │   │
    │       │   ├───Entity
    │       │   │       EntityCommonReturn.py
    │       │   │       EntityCommonShipping.py
    │       │   │
    │       │   └───UsefulClasses
    │       │           ConfigurationSystem.py
    │       │           Global.py
    │       │           LanguageCommon.py
    │       │           LogSystem.py
    │       │           UtilityMethodsCommon.py
    │       │
    │       ├───obj
    │       │   ├───Debug
    │       │   │       M.DO.AppDesktop.Form.FrmLoading.resources
    │       │   │       M.DO.AppDesktop.Form.FrmShipping.resources
    │       │   │       M.DO.dll
    │       │   │       M.DO.exe
    │       │   │       M.DO.Process.Form.MainProcess.resources
    │       │   │       M.DO.pyproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
    │       │   │       M.DO.pyproj.GenerateResource.Cache
    │       │   │       M.DO.pyprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache
    │       │   │
    │       │   └───Release
    │       │           M.DO.AppDesktop.Form.FrmLoading.resources
    │       │           M.DO.AppDesktop.Form.FrmShipping.resources
    │       │           M.DO.dll
    │       │           M.DO.exe
    │       │           M.DO.Process.Form.MainProcess.resources
    │       │           M.DO.pyproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
    │       │           M.DO.pyproj.GenerateResource.Cache
    │       │           M.DO.pyprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache
    │       │
    │       └───Process
    │           │   billing_situation_R1.txt
    │           │   billing_situation_R2.txt
    │           │   reason_for_billing_status_R1.txt
    │           │   reason_for_billing_status_R2.txt
    │           │
    │           ├───DAO
    │           │   └───Persistence
    │           │           PersistenceProcessReturn.py
    │           │           PersistenceProcessShipping.py
    │           │
    │           └───Form
    │                   MainProcess.py
    │                   MainProcess.resx
    │
    └───Library
        │   Library.sln
        │
        ├───.vs
        │   └───Library
        │       ├───v14
        │       │       .suo
        │       │
        │       └───v15
        ├───ConfigurationManagerLibrary
        │   │   ConfigurationManagerLibrary.csproj
        │   │   Util.cs
        │   │
        │   ├───bin
        │   │   ├───Debug
        │   │   │       ConfigurationManagerLibrary.dll
        │   │   │       ConfigurationManagerLibrary.pdb
        │   │   │
        │   │   └───Release
        │   ├───obj
        │   │   │
        │   │   └───Release
        │   │       │   CoreCompileInputs.cache
        │   │       │   DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferencesInput.cache
        │   │       │
        │   │       └───TempPE
        │   └───Properties
        │           AssemblyInfo.cs
        │
        ├───ListViewLibrary
        │   │   ListViewExtender.cs
        │   │   ListViewLibrary.csproj
        │   │   OrderListView.cs
        │   │
        │   ├───bin
        │   │   ├───Debug
        │   │   │       ListViewLibrary.dll
        │   │   │       ListViewLibrary.pdb
        │   │   │
        │   │   └───Release
        │   │           ListViewLibrary.dll
        │   │           ListViewLibrary.pdb
        │   │
        │   ├───obj
        │   │   ├───Debug
        │   │   │       CoreCompileInputs.cache
        │   │   │       DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferencesInput.cache
        │   │   │       ListViewLibrary.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
        │   │   │       ListViewLibrary.dll
        │   │   │       ListViewLibrary.pdb
        │   │   │
        │   │   └───Release
        │   │       │   CoreCompileInputs.cache
        │   │       │   DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferencesInput.cache
        │   │       │   ListViewLibrary.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
        │   │       │   ListViewLibrary.dll
        │   │       │   ListViewLibrary.pdb
        │   │       │
        │   │       └───TempPE
        │   └───Properties
        │           AssemblyInfo.cs
        │
        └───MessageBoxLibrary
            │   MessageBoxLibrary.csproj
            │   PropertyMessageBox.cs
            │
            ├───bin
            │   ├───Debug
            │   └───Release
            │           MessageBoxLibrary.dll
            │           MessageBoxLibrary.pdb
            │
            ├───obj
            │   ├───Debug
            │   │       CoreCompileInputs.cache
            │   │
            │   └───Release
            │       │   CoreCompileInputs.cache
            │       │   DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferencesInput.cache
            │       │   MessageBoxLibrary.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
            │       │   MessageBoxLibrary.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache
            │       │   MessageBoxLibrary.dll
            │       │   MessageBoxLibrary.pdb
            │       │   TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs
            │       │   TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs
            │       │   TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs
            │       │
            │       └───TempPE
            └───Properties
                    AssemblyInfo.cs
```

Comment: did you output the `Global.configurationmanagerlibrary_dll_path` to see what file it is referring ? even with a simple  `print()`

Comment: configurationmanagerlibrary_dll_path = `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()  + '//Common//DLL//ConfigurationManagerLibrary.dll'`  that's part of the project

Comment: is this '//' or '\\' ?

Comment: `'//'` just checked.

Comment: i assume you're running this on a windows OS, maybe try with '\\', plus i can't see a reason to double the slash, double the backslash makes more sense

Comment: It seems to be a problem with assembly loading since this project is on a network.

Comment: what matter is : from the running location, what is the path to get to ConfigurationManagerLibrary.dll ?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2004/12/30/using-caspol-to-fully-trust-a-share/